# How do I change the site admin in a flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, http-400-bad-request

I can set a new user as the site admin with the following request:

[image]

Then I want to remove the original site admin with:

[image]

But I get the error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"**The parameter IsSiteAdmin does not exist in method GetUserById**."}}}

Which it obviously does, because i just used it to set the new user's parameter to true!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I simply missed the X-HTTP-Method in the second call.

[image]